# What does "diversant" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

However, conflicting orders and German diversants operating in the rear disrupted both attacks and led to chaos in the Polish ranks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a transliteration of the Russian word диверсант, which means saboteur.  From *[Cinepaternity: Fathers and Sons in Soviet and Post-Soviet Film](https://books.google.com/books?id=9clS9PG0KSwC&pg=PA109&dq=%22diversant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM06fArrbJAhUFaz4KHdt8DkI4ChDoAQhHMAg#v=onepage&q=%22diversant%22&f=false)* by Helena Goscilo, Yana Hashamova:

> The TV mini-series **Diversant** [The Saboteur, Andrei Maliukov 2004]
>   depicts the rigorous training of young soldiers to transform them into
>   professional saboteurs.[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=9clS9PG0KSwC&pg=PA109&dq=%22diversant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM06fArrbJAhUFaz4KHdt8DkI4ChDoAQhHMAg#v=onepage&q=%22diversant%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard this word, it is not in the OED, and the GloWbE (corpus of web-based English) has only one instance of it, again referring to Germans.

My guess is that it is a German word which some writers have erroneously supposed existed in English.

**Edit**: Found it in [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversant). It says it means a saboteur, in Communist-speak (and gives its origin from a Russian word Диверсия "Diversiya").